# Magento 2 Notice: Undefined index RendererFactory.php on line 64

Tags: magento2

Once per day I got my production server down with this error

> Notice: Undefined index
>   ....vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Page/Config/RendererFactory.php
>   on line 64

I've checked config for `dev/front_end_development_workflow/type` and it exists in `database` also and as default config in `xml`.
Magento version 2.1.7

This error **fixes with clearing cache** but it's not a solution to do every time.
Does anybody faced with this issue?

Comment: i have the same issue , any idea?

Comment: I am having the same issue, are you running a multi-site setup? are you running with Redis?

Comment: Nag Kernez, did you have any luck resolving this issue? I'm experiencing the same error and am curious how you solved it.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the fix here :

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8619

It worked for me and that is to set the compiling to `server side less compilation` and then deleted the row (for some reason).

After that re-run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

You can find the setting in : **Stores->Configuration->Advanced->Developer-> turn to default settings scope -> Front end workflow**

Answer (score 0):

1) open PHPMyAdmin

2) select your database

3) go to **core_config_data** file

4) run this query

```
UPDATE `magento`.`core_config_data` SET `value` = '0' WHERE core_config_data`.`config_id` = 5;
```

5) and also

```
UPDATE `magento`.`core_config_data` SET `value` = '0' WHERE `core_config_data`.`config_id` = 6;
```

It works definitely!

Comment: I would never trust the config_id value to point to a specific configuration parameter, I would use the path.

Comment: you can run this command : php bin/magento setup:di:compile  and then refresh the frontend page , it's works

Answer (score 0):

To see the correct error message, 
try to switch on developer mode "bin/magento deploy:mode:set" and disable all cache